# CSS child div extends with it's content even if it's parent has fixed height

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a parent `<div>` with a fixed height and with flex item children.

Is there a way to have its children height **not fixed but extending depending on their content** ?

```css
.main-container {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
.div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
.div2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.div3 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightpink;
}
div p {
  font-size: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="div1">
    <p>a</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">q</div>
  <div class="div3">s</div>
</div>
```

Wanted result : [image]

Comment: What would be the purpose of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `fit-content` (which is not supported in Firefox: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_height_fit-content), you simply need to disable the stertch effect by adding `align-self:flex-start;` to the needed element

```css
.main-container {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
.div1 {
  width: 100%;
  align-self:flex-start;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
.div2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.div3 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightpink;
}
div p {
  font-size: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="div1">
    <p>a</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">q</div>
  <div class="div3">s</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, though can you add some details to explain why this property is making the trick ?

Comment: @LoganWlv the default alignment is `stretch` (https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-align-items) which means an element will take the height of the parent. You disable this by a different alignment and the height will be auto and will follow the content

Comment: Ok thank you ! One last question does there is a way to keep this behaviour and having every flex items having the same height?

Comment: @LoganWlv you will probably need an extra container: https://jsfiddle.net/14uzjqv7/1/

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to have its children height not fixed but extending depending on their content ?

If you want a div to be as high as it content needs, you can apply `height: fit-content;` on that div.

Example in the snippet below (for the left column):

```css
.main-container {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
.div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
.div2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.div3 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightpink;
}
div p {
  font-size: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="div1">
    <p>a</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">q</div>
  <div class="div3">s</div>
</div>
```